# Location and region finding from the user ip address

Tags: php, geolocation, location, maps

Am using this code for getting the location of the IP address.

> `$location = file_get_contents('http://freegeoip.net/json/'.'117.253.168.187');`

Here is my problem when i provide the ip address as **117.253.168.187** country is listing as proper IN but the region is return empty value.

> `{"ip":"117.253.168.187","country_code":"IN","country_name":"India","region_code":"","region_name":"","city":"","zipcode":"","latitude":20,"longitude":77,"metro_code":"","area_code":""}`

If i change the ip as **122.166.65.125** its return the proper region with country.

> {"ip":"122.166.65.125","country_code":"IN","country_name":"India","region_code":"19","region_name":"Karnataka","city":"Bangalore","zipcode":"","latitude":12.9833,"longitude":77.5833,"metro_code":"","area_code":""}

I don't know why this api showing empty regions in some IP address ??

I have a redirect in my page depends on the region. So how can i solve the region issue ??

am collecting dummy ip address from INTERNET eg:http://myip.ms/view/cities/67445/IP_Addresses_Cochin.html

Anyone can help me for finding solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because my be freegeoip.net does not have complete region information for IP 117.253.168.187.
I have also tried lots of ip to location but only paid one works fine. You may use http://www.ip2location.com/demo

Answer (score 1):

The freegeoip.net is the free IP to location service and has been deprecated after getting acquired by IP Stack. I have been using [ipgeolocation.io](https://ipgeolocation.io) and it provides complete location for all the IP addresses.

You can consume 30K requests per month (1K requests per day) in the free plan with all the location features same as for paid plans.

Here are their links to test [IP location](https://ipgeolocation.io/ip-location) and the complete [documentation](https://ipgeolocation.io/documentation.html).

Answer (score 1):

The results from **[IPinfo](https://www.ipinfo.io)** looks like this:

> **117.253.168.187**

```bash
curl https://ipinfo.io/117.253.168.187/json
```

```json
{
  "ip": "117.253.168.187",
  "city": "Dharwad",
  "region": "Karnataka",
  "country": "IN",
  "loc": "15.4601,75.0078",
  "org": "AS9829 National Internet Backbone",
  "postal": "580009",
  "timezone": "Asia/Kolkata"
}
```

> **122.166.65.125**

```
curl https://ipinfo.io/122.166.65.125/json
```

```json
{
  "ip": "122.166.65.125",
  "hostname": "abts-kk-static-125.65.166.122.airtelbroadband.in",
  "city": "Bengaluru",
  "region": "Karnataka",
  "country": "IN",
  "loc": "12.9719,77.5937",
  "org": "AS24560 Bharti Airtel Ltd., Telemedia Services",
  "postal": "560002",
  "timezone": "Asia/Kolkata"
}
```

On IPinfo's free tier with upto 50,000 requests per month, you can get all the field that you require for region based redirect, such as:

- city
- region
- country
- latitude and longitude

You can use our service through:

- IPinfo API: https://ipinfo.io/developers
- IPinfo PHP Library: https://github.com/ipinfo/php